# WebStorm went into EADDRINUSE when “Stop & Rerun” Node.js task

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I use WebStorm as IDE. Also I run my Node.js scripts as WebStorm Run/Debug configurations and rerun it on `Shift + F10`.

After I updates WebStorm to WebStorm 2017.3 every time I tried to rerun current task I got an Error EADDRINUSE.

That`s why WebStorm does not close Node.js process when rerun it. And old process still use its port.

Every time I should go to the Task Manager and close Node.js processes manually.

Is there any workaround to fix it and force WebStorm to close Node.js processes on rerun?

P.S. Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

In you run configuration, make sure to tick **Single instance only** checkbox; or, use `Ctrl+F5` rather than `Shift + F10` to re-run.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is checked. 

`Ctrl + F5` has the same effect as `Shift + F10`.

Comment: can't recreate; please create a support ticket and share a sample project that shows up the issue